# PostgreSQL trigger and function to update a table using a three table join/subquery search

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, triggers

I am trying to write a trigger with a function to update the value of a column in one table while performing a search with a join with three tables.

What I want to do is increment the number of active members in each group a member is in when the member becomes active.
So if a member is in group A and group B, when they become active, group A's and group B's numactivemembers will each increment by 1.

```
Table member
name
church
state (0 is inactive, 1 is active)

Table churchgrp
church
grp
numactivemembers

Table memberchurchgrp
name
church
grp
```

This SELECT gets me the correct rows:

```
SELECT cg.church, cg.grp, cg.numactivemembers FROM churchgrp cg inner join memberchurchgrp ucg ON cg.church = ucg.church AND cg.grp = ucg.grp inner join member u ON m.name = ucg.name AND m.church = ucg.church AND ucg.grp = cg.grp WHERE m.name = 'John Doe' AND m.state = 1;
```

I have the trigger working on update of the state of the member.

```
CREATE TRIGGER inc_grpnumactivemembers_tgr
  AFTER UPDATE ON member
  FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN OLD.state = 0 AND NEW.state = 1
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE incgrpnumactivemembers();
```

What is not working is the update in the function.

This executes, but increments all rows in churchgrp, not just the groups the member is in, which is incorrect.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION incgrpnumactivemembers()
RETURNS trigger AS
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE churchgrp SET numactivemembers = num_active_members + 1 FROM (SELECT cg.church, cg.grp, cg.numactivemembers FROM churchgrp cg inner join memberchurchgrp ucg ON cg.church = ucg.church AND cg.grp = ucg.grp inner join member u ON m.name = ucg.name AND m.church = ucg.church AND ucg.grp = cg.grp WHERE m.name = NEW.name AND m.state = 1)
AS sq
RETURN NEW;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

This update gives me this error: ERROR:  table name "cg" specified more than once

```
UPDATE churchgrp as cg SET numactivemembers = num_active_members + 1 FROM churchgrp cg inner join memberchurchgrp ucg ON cg.church = ucg.church AND cg.grp = ucg.grp inner join member u ON m.name = ucg.name AND m.church = ucg.church AND ucg.grp = cg.grp WHERE m.name = NEW.name AND m.state = 1)
```

This update gives me this error: ERROR:  column reference "numactivemembers" is ambiguous LINE 1: UPDATE churchgroup SET numactivemembers = numactivem...

```
UPDATE churchgrp SET numactivemembers = num_active_members + 1 FROM churchgrp cg inner join memberchurchgrp ucg ON cg.church = ucg.church AND cg.grp = ucg.grp inner join member u ON m.name = ucg.name AND m.church = ucg.church AND ucg.grp = cg.grp WHERE m.name = NEW.name AND m.state = 1;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint:  Triggers should be using "new" and "old".

Comment: NEW and OLD are being used in both the trigger and function.  I used this page as a reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/plpgsql-trigger.html